# Angular2 Whitescreen of death

Tags: angular

When I load my application the first time (no cache etc), it works perfectly fine.
But when I reload, the page only loads in the app component. any lazy-loaded route is not working anymore..

Upgraded to latest angular-cli & angular:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-beta.30
node: 6.9.5
os: linux x64
@angular/common: 2.4.6
@angular/compiler: 2.4.6
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.6
@angular/core: 2.4.6
@angular/forms: 2.4.6
@angular/http: 2.4.6
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.6
@angular/router: 3.4.6
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-beta.30
@ngtools/webpack: 1.2.8
```

Visual representation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqO9P2DnThc&feature=youtu.be

hard reload with deleting cache > works again, then reload normal > white screen with just the app component being loaded.

The "Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode." is not shown when the problem exists either.

Comment: try to adding at your index.html  <base href="/">

Comment: It's there @YoavSchniederma, otherwise it wouldn't load at all, it's only blank when I refresh normally.